# Spanner IAM Permissions for inherited principals

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-spanner

I have a spanner instance in my GCP project

I see all the inherited principals which are coming from the parent project who can access my instance and database from console.

I tried to attach a policy through terraform using

```
data "google_iam_policy" "admin" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/editor"

    members = [
      "user:jane@example.com",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_spanner_instance_iam_policy" "instance" {
  instance    = "your-instance-name"
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.admin.policy_data
}
```

I have also tried the below separately

```
resource "google_spanner_instance_iam_binding" "spanner_instance_iam_policy" {
  instance = module.spanner_instance.instance.name
  role = "roles/owner"

  members = [
    "user:xuxy@fthtfhht.com",
    "serviceAccount:fhfhfh@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  ]
}
```

My understanding is that both policy and binding is authoritative
So the principal permissions in console should be replaced by the things which I mention in the above policy or binding.

But I still see the inherited principals and their permissions still exists.

Is there a way to remove access/permissions for all the inherited principals and only restrict to a list of principal which I want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deny inherited principals at the resource level. You can create an IAM Deny Policy and attach it at the project level.

[Google Cloud IAM Deny Policy](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-overview)

Unless you also specify deny conditions, you would block those permissions for all resources in the project for those principals.

[Deny Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference#resource-tags)